# how to change color of the selected words in EditText

Tags: java, android, colors, android-edittext

I'm creating a text editor, and i wont to able users to select some words in EditText and change color of the selected words, 
How can I do that? Or how can i understand which words, user selected? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [getSelectionStart](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getSelectionStart()) and [getSelectionEnd](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getSelectionEnd()) to get the active selection.

Use [SpannableString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html) and [SpannableString.setSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html#setSpan(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int,%20int)) to colorize the selection using a [ForegroundColorSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ForegroundColorSpan.html).